# How to secure a document/pdf request in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am wondering what is the preferred practice to secure document.

If I have a link in my page like:

```
option 1)   http://myserver/documents/mydoc.pdf
```

can I secure it using a filter to check if the user is logged in or has the correct role?

my first thinking was to create an action call ViewDoc. In ViewDoc I would check the permissions etc and then read the file in and send it to the response.

so my request would look something like this:

```
option 2)    http://myserver/mycontroller/ViewDoc/17
```

If I go with option 2, do I need to have my files outside the web folder? If I have in the web folder, could a user make a request directly to the file?
any other options or suggestions?

Comment: Just return the Document througt a Action with the Authorize attribute

Comment: Yeah that was what I was going to do. I was wondering if there are simpler ways.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution is the correct way to do this.

You will use a [`FileResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) action (unless you have good reason not to) and in that action you will probably use `[Authorize]` and perform any business logic necessary to validate the user should be reading it. Then you return the file using the controller's [`File()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx) function.

```
[Authorize]
public FileResult ViewDoc(int id)
{
    // do things, maybe lookup file path of document from database
    return File(pathToYourFile, "document/pdf", "downloadedFileName.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the Document througt a Action with the Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetFile(string filename)
{
  //get the file somewhere
  return return File(file, "contentType");
}
```

Comment: Where should I place the files? Outside the web folder? What if I place it in the web folder, should I secure that folder in the web.config?

Comment: It's better to place this files outside the application, somewhere, like a file server.